# Slow fetching of contents from URL

Tags: php, android, urlconnection

I am trying to fetch the contents of [this](http://kbtganesh.16mb.com/index.php) url. The contents will get changed for each refresh.

I am wrote my code to fetch the content and display it in my app using TextView by a Button Click.

But it takes more time ( Minimum 2 seconds , Maximum 6 seconds ) to get the data and display into Textview. So what change do i need in my code to make it **efficiant** and reduce the delay.

---

### Here is my code,

( Fetching done in **getData**() method using **URLConnection** method )

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView resultView;
    String TAG="MainActivity kbt";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

        try {
            getData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Button insert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    getData();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

 
    public void getData() throws IOException {

        String result = "";
        InputStream isr = null;

        URLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = new URL("http://kbtganesh.16mb.com/index.php"); 
        urlConnection =  url.openConnection();
        isr =urlConnection.getInputStream();
        try {  
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();

            result=sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //parse json data
        try {
            resultView.setText(result);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Couldn't set text, damnit.");
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance (:

Comment: You can do nothing, if Web service itself is slow. You need to tell the developer..

Comment: But When i try with browser, it was perfect.

Comment: I am using kitkat in my phone ( Where i tested ) and target sdk is 23... I am not getting you  **It looks like you're doing a network operation on the main thread**  ??? What do you mean?

Comment: Where do i need to do these operations @DanielNugent

Comment: I would have thought you would be getting a NetworkOnMainThreadException, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: I checked in chrome debugger.. your service is taking atleast 1.93 seconds to response...

Comment: @ChintanSoni While starting an app, it takes around 5 seconds. After some time of using app, its taking 2 seconds to load

Comment: @ChintanSoni :  Daniel is saying something about **NetworkOnMainThreadException** which i think that could be the reason for the delay at starting time of the app. Am i right ?

Comment: So don't do network operations on main thread.

Comment: @DanielNugent Thanks mate.. I'll put these into AsyncTask...

Comment: Yes.. Ofcourse he is right.. Dont ever do network operations on main thread.. Because of your this line, `StrictMode.enableDefaults();` its not throwing any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try test it in on a local server on your computer, instead of a remote one like you have. Sometimes it's just slow internet speed slowing the page down, and nothing to do with the code.

Comment: Dude, i am not having local server thats why i choosed remote server.

Comment: Just test it on a local server. If it works up to speed, then you know that it's your internet, and not the code. Otherwise, it might then be the code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `StrictMode.enableDefaults();` instead use the AsyncTask to fetch the data from the network as doc says

**"Keeping disk and network operations off the main thread makes for much smoother, more responsive applications"**

check doc here [StrictMode Doce](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)

Else everything looks fine you can also check the improvment on the webservice end check the query it can be optimized as there is a very less data your api is returns